# Error Use of unresolved identifier 'PFFacebookUtils' in line PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions

Tags: facebook, parse-platform, swift2, xcode7, facebook-ios-sdk

[image]

I get the following error after I've updated to the latest version of Parse and also updated to the latest version of the iOS Facebook SDK and ParseFacebookUtils with the following command in my PodFile.

```
pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'
```

Since the PFFacebookUtils framework has been updated, I'm not too sure what the correct logInWithPermissions method should be for this updated framework?

Answer (score 0):

I've had to make use of the following code to login.

```
    let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
```